# Change places custom fields with title field in post wp-admin

Tags: posts

Is it possible to make custom fields at the top, when writing a new post in admin panel ?

Thank you.

Comment: Top of the edit screen?

Comment: Yes above title input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function wpse81499_move_postcustom_to_top()
{
    if( 'post' != get_current_screen()->id )
        return;
    ?>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#postcustom').prependTo('#titlediv');
    });
</script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'wpse81499_move_postcustom_to_top' );
```